# Log4j2 JSONLayout gives error

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

i am try to config my log4j2 but i always get this errors:

```
2017-11-06 01:14:15,454 RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1 ERROR appender RollingFile has no parameter that matches element PatternLayout
2017-11-06 01:14:15,478 RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1 ERROR appender RollingFile has no parameter that matches element PatternLayout
2017-11-06 01:14:15,484 RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1 ERROR appender RollingFile has no parameter that matches element JSONLayout
```

The last error is for "mylevs" appender. Result: i get JSON format logs for warn and error, but for mylevel there is usual data format.
What could cause this errors?

My log4j2.xml config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" strict="true" name="XMLConfigTest"
               packages="org.apache.logging.log4j.test">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="logsPath">F:/Projects/Work/DSTULib/logs/ULS</Property>
    </Properties>

    <CustomLevel name="MYLEVEL" intLevel="700" />

    <Appenders>

        <RollingFile name="errors" fileName="${logsPath}/errors.log"
                     filePattern="'.'%d{yyyy-MM-dd}'.log.zip'">
            <JSONLayout compact="true" eventEol="true"/>
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%n%n%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="FATAL" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
                <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            </Filters>
        </RollingFile>

        <RollingFile name="warns" fileName="${logsPath}/warns.log"
                     filePattern="'.'%d{yyyy-MM-dd}'.log.zip'">
            <JSONLayout compact="true" eventEol="true"/>
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%n%n%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
                <ThresholdFilter level="WARN" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            </Filters>
        </RollingFile>

        <RollingFile name="mylevs" fileName="${logsPath}/mylevel.log"
                     filePattern="'.'%d{yyyy-MM-dd}'.log.zip'">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%n%n%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="TRACE" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
                <ThresholdFilter level="MYLEVEL" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            </Filters>
            <JSONLayout compact="true" eventEol="true"/>
        </RollingFile>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="mylevs" level="mylevel" />
            <AppenderRef ref="errors" level="error"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="warns" level="warn"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

PS: i am following documentation guide. 
And this text to pass this quastion, so please don't read this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define exactly one layout per appender. But you are defining two layouts for each one. Try removing one layout from each of your appenders.

Comment: Is JSONLayout == PatternLayout? May be there is some composit layout, like with filters?